# ID from snapshot angular routing is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I pass in student id when user try to update student. It successfully goes to updateStudent page and also shows student id on browserlink, however, in my app component, it says that it is undefined.

**Student View component to send sid to update Student component: **

```
 updateStudent(id: number) {
   console.log(id);
   this.router.navigate(['/updateStudent', id]);
 }
```

**Update Student component:**

```
export class UpdateStudentComponent implements OnInit {
 id: number;
 constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router{
     this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
     console.log(this.id);
   }
}
```

**Routing Module:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
 path: 'studentsList', component: StudentsListComponent },
 path: 'updateStudent/: id', component: UpdateStudentComponent },
 path: ' ', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full' },
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

use `params.subscribe` instead also your param in your router module is named as `sid` so it should be sid instead of id

```
 this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
     this.id = params['sid'];
     console.log(this.id);
 })
```

Comment: This still shows undefined

Comment: you are checking it in `UpdateStudentComponent ` component right?

Comment: Yes, it send student id from student view component to updateStudentComponent

Comment: you defined the param in your routing module as `sid` so it should be params['sid'] check updated ans

Comment: I fixed the sid to id in my routing modules, however, still the same issue

Comment: why do you have space after `:` it should be `:id` without space.If it still not works please create a stackblitz example of your issue and share the link